# Set Monaco Editor in React to read-only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, monaco-editor

Having the following code snippet:

```
import React from "react";

import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react";

function App() {
  return (
    <Editor
      height="90vh"
      defaultLanguage="javascript"
      defaultValue="// some comment"
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

and [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-usage-uyf5n?file=/src/App.js:0-239)

Is it possible to make it read-only? I've found some examples but they aren't working for this type of editor, is it possible to set read-only to true or some other method for the above code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `options` prop is of type `IStandaloneEditorConstructionOptions`. There you have `readOnly` and `domReadOnly` flags, cf. https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.IStandaloneEditorConstructionOptions.html#readOnly

`options={{domReadOnly: true}}` appears to make the editor read-only, whereas `options={{readOnly: true}}` furthermore adds a tooltip.